# Не могу убрать пароль на связку ключей в Linux Mint 20.3 Una

Tags: linux

У меня стоит Linux Mint 20.3 Una, при каждом входе в броузер Google Chrome постоянно выскакивает окно с требованием ввести пароль, это как бы не напрягает, но уже порядком надоело. Причём если первым запускаю Skype, тоже просит ввести пароль, но после этого набираю Google Chrome то пароль уже не требует и наоборот. Подскажите, как убрать эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

чтоб снять пароль нужно или отключить автоматический вход в систему или открой программу seahorse. там связка ключей вход - сменить пароль - установи пустой пароль.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это удалите, а сам пароль в имя локальной учетной записи можно поставить.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]